# Proof that a $Ax \le b$ with $A\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is not a polyhedron

Tags: polyhedra, integer-programming, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

Consider \begin{align}\min \sqrt2 x_1 - x_2 \\ 1 \leq x_2 \leq \sqrt2 x_1 \\ x_1,x_2\text{ integer.} \end{align}

How do you show that $conv\{x \in \mathbb{Z}^2: 1 \leq x_2 \leq \sqrt2 x_1\} $ is not a polyhedron?

I know by Meyer's Theorem that it is a polyhedron if it can be represented with a system $Ax\leq b$ with rational $A,b$, but the converse it not true in general.

Using Minkowski-Weyl (a polyhedron is the Minkowski sum of the convex hull $Q$ of a finite number of points, say $v^1,...,v^p$, and the finitely generated cone C with generators $r^1,...,r^q$), I find that it has extreme ray $(1,0)$. I expect that there are infinitely points $v^1,...,v^p$, which results in $conv\{x \in \mathbb{Z}^2: 1 \leq x_2 \leq \sqrt2 x_1\} $  not being a polyhedron, but how to prove this exactely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** As [mr-e-man](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/472818/mr-e-man) has pointed out in his comment both of my previous suggestions for answering this question were wrong. I can't delete this post until it has been unaccepted.  In the meantime, mr-e-man's comments effectively give a proper answer.

Comment: No, $(1,\sqrt2)$ is not in the closure. The leftmost vertex is $(1,1)$; from there the lower edge has slope $0$ and the upper edge has slope $\tfrac32$ (connecting to $(3,4)$ and $(5,7)$ and no other lattice points); since $\tfrac32<\infty$, the convex hull is bounded away from $(1,\sqrt2)$.

Comment: Oops. It looks like I was thinking of $\ x_1\ $ and $\ x_2\ $ being in $\ \mathbb{Q}\ $ rather than $\ \mathbb{Z}\ $.

Comment: No again; I think "polyhedron" here means an intersection of finitely many half-spaces, which is possibly unbounded. A "polytope" is a bounded polyhedron.

Comment: This object is obviously not 3D, so it's not a polyhedron in the usual sense.

Comment: What makes this object not a "polyhedron" is that it has infinitely many edges. Each edge has a rational slope, and these slopes must approach $\sqrt2$.

Comment: [polyhedron vs polytope](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4021223/472818)